# Find all possible path between two nodes in a undirected graph

Tags: c

Can anybody give me a C Code to find all possible paths between two nodes?
eg.
if the graph has following edges
1-2
1-3
2-3
2-4
3-4

all paths between 1 and 4 are:

1-2-3-4

1-2-4

1-3-4

1-3-2-4

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713508/find-the-paths-between-two-given-nodes

Answer (score 3):

A Depth-First Search does this job.

Comment: Not really.  DFS might give you a few paths, but not all of them.

Comment: @Keith. Think about a dfs solution to n-queen problem.

Comment: The solution I think you're thinking of (loop over all possible squares, place a queen there if possible, and recurse) is not DFS.

Comment: DFS doesn't revisit nodes it has visited already.  If you're doing that (as you would need to do for the OP's problem), I wouldn't call it DFS.  Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) agrees with me.  I'll grant you, though, if you allow revisiting completed but not in progress nodes, you'll likely solve the OP's problem.

Comment: @Keith: since the opening of the Wikipedia article says *Depth-first search (DFS) is an algorithm  for traversing or searching a tree, tree structure, or graph. One starts at the root (selecting some node as the root in the graph case) and explores as far as possible along each branch before backtracking*, I'm not convinced that supports your thesis.  It explicitly mentions back-tracking, which is what is needed to ensure complete coverage.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm assuming you don't want repeated nodes in your path - otherwise the number of possible paths is infinite.)

You can do a relaxation:

```
while (there is a change) {
  for (v in nodes(G)) {
    for (e in edges(v)) {
      paths_to[v] = paths_to[v] union ((paths_to[e.to] not containing v) append v)
    }
  }
}
```

The result can still be exponential in the size of the input graph.  Getting all paths is probably not what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple algorithm to the problem.  It is not an optimal algorithm.

```
static struct {
  int value1;
  int value2;
  int used;
} data[] = {
  { 1, 2 },
  { 1, 3 },
  { 2, 3 },
  { 2, 4 },
  { 3, 4 },
};

enum { DATA_SIZE = sizeof data / sizeof *data };

static int output[DATA_SIZE];

int traverse(int from, int to, int depth) {
  output[depth++] = from;

  int i;
  if (from == to) {
    for (i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
      if (i) {
        printf("-");
      }
      printf("%d", output[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  } else {
    for (i = 0; i < DATA_SIZE; i++) {
      if (!data[i].used) {
        data[i].used = 1;

        if (from == data[i].value1) {
          traverse(data[i].value2, to, depth);
        } else if (from == data[i].value2) {
          traverse(data[i].value1, to, depth);
        }

        data[i].used = 0;
      }
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  traverse(1, 4, 0);
}
```

Comment: hi bkail,
thanks for your program.but i am finding some difficulties while checking for the following nodes,too many cycles are coming.

can you try the following edges and find path having no repeated nodes between 1 and 4

 {0, 5}, {1 ,4}, {0, 2},
{5 ,4 }, {1 ,2 }, {4 ,3 }, {3 ,10}, {1, 6 }, {6 ,2 }, {2 ,3 }, {2, 7 }, {3 ,14 }, {6, 7 }, {7, 8 }, {8, 10 }, {8, 9 }, {8 ,12 }, {8 ,14}, {5 ,11 }, {10 ,11 }, {10 ,13}, {10 ,9 }, {11 ,14 }, {11 ,12 }, {12 ,13 }, {13 ,14 },

Answer (score 0):

a recursive method:

```
findPaths(path = startNode, goal)
    paths = []
    if the last node in path is goal:
        return path
    for each node n connected to the last node in path:
        if n is not already on the path:
            paths.append(findPaths(path.append(node), goal))
    return paths //may still be []
```

Answer (score 0):

It is too late and not the C code but may be help others. This algo show how I implement it in java.

```
findPath(start) 
    Childs = getDirectChildsOf(start)
    foreach child in Childs
        tempRoute;
        tempRoute.add(start)
        if (child == end)
            return tempRoute.add(child) 
        else 
            tempRoute.add(findPath(child))
            if (tempRoute.last() == end)
                return tempRoute;
```

Here `tempRoute` may be a `Route` class that maintain a list of node. Able to add single `node` and other `route` to `tempRoute`. 
It also not find all possible path. for that you have to maintain a visited flag for each node.