# all paths between two nodes on the basis of edges

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, networkx

My problem is [all simple paths](http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads//HTML/simplepath.html) problem on hallucinogens. I need to find all the paths between two nodes on the basis of the edges and not nodes

[I found this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576675-bfs-breadth-first-search-graph-traversal/) as a solution but this approach is way too slow considering the size of my actual graph. 
I would like to know what are the optimizations that could be done to better this.
I have modified the code given in the link to use deque()
[This is not of too much help either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713508/find-the-paths-between-two-given-nodes)
  `g=nx.MultiGraph()
  g.add_edge(1,1,key='a')
  g.add_edge(1,2,key='b')
  g.add_edge(2,4,key='c')
  g.add_edge(2,4,key='d')
  g.add_edge(3,2,key='e')
  g.add_edge(3,3,key='f')
  g.add_edge(1,3,key='g')
  g.add_edge(1,5,key='h')
  g.add_edge(5,5,key='i')`


The Answer for all_path(1,4):

```
Path: 0 --> [(1, 1, 'a'), (1, 2, 'b'), (2, 4, 'c')]
Path: 1 --> [(1, 1, 'a'), (1, 2, 'b'), (2, 4, 'd')]
Path: 2 --> [(1, 1, 'a'), (1, 3, 'g'), (3, 2, 'e'), (2, 4, 'c')]
Path: 3 --> [(1, 1, 'a'), (1, 3, 'g'), (3, 2, 'e'), (2, 4, 'd')]
Path: 4 --> [(1, 1, 'a'), (1, 3, 'g'), (3, 3, 'f'), (3, 2, 'e'), (2, 4, 'c')]
Path: 5 --> [(1, 1, 'a'), (1, 3, 'g'), (3, 3, 'f'), (3, 2, 'e'), (2, 4, 'd')]
Path: 6 --> [(1, 2, 'b'), (2, 4, 'c')]
Path: 7 --> [(1, 2, 'b'), (2, 4, 'd')]
Path: 8 --> [(1, 3, 'g'), (3, 2, 'e'), (2, 4, 'c')]
Path: 9 --> [(1, 3, 'g'), (3, 2, 'e'), (2, 4, 'd')]
Path: 10 --> [(1, 3, 'g'), (3, 3, 'f'), (3, 2, 'e'), (2, 4, 'c')]
Path: 11 --> [(1, 3, 'g'), (3, 3, 'f'), (3, 2, 'e'), (2, 4, 'd')]
```

Comment: You may like to describe the size of your graph. Is the usage of `multigraph` absolutely necessary?

Comment: @eat, Absolutely, there are a quite a few situations where there are more than one edge between between 2 neighbors

Comment: @Ashish, Can't. DFS needs to be recursive. The program stack would blow up

Comment: So, how many nodes and edges? Do you have any estimation on the number possible paths? Why DFS needs to be recursive? Won't a own queue be sufficient? Al tough I don't know whether BFS versus DFS makes any difference, since you need all paths. Just an idea; try to find out paths from simple graph and then add those multi edges.

Comment: There are about 2.5 million edges. I am unable to estimate the number of paths. I am currently using an iterative BFS for solving this problem. As a modification, I am limiting the path length to 20 hops, so it works fine for now. But I might have to something about it very soon

Answer (score 0):

Try to build new graph with where current edges are transformed into nodes and there is an edge beetween two nodes if we can use their corresponding edges consequently in a path. After it you can solve your problem with DFS.

Comment: 1) DFS needs to be recursive, which is unaffordable.

Comment: 2)The method you suggest needs way too much computational power