# Algorithm to compute every path in a N by N grid, non-repeating

Tags: algorithm, graph, matrix, graph-algorithm

I have a grid of NxN cells (think of a 2 dimensional array defined as follows Array[N][N]).

Which algorithm will compute **every path** from every cell a[i][j] to every cell a[k][l] where:

1. No cell is included twice within a single path.
2. Only **adjacent** diagonal, horizontal and vertical moves all legal.
3. The algorithm is the fastest, on average.
4. The least amount of memory is used.

Comment: Good question. Seems like a dynamic programming problem.

Comment: I would change `5 by 5` to `N by N` before someone answer with an algorithm with a pre-calculated hard-coded answer.

Comment: Djkistra's shortest path algorithm I'd imagine, take a quick look here for more information, it might help you come up with a solution. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Comment: This sounds like a variation of the travelling salesman problem making it NP Complete and requiring a brute-force solution. You need to me more specific about the rules. Are you allowed to move diagonally (0,0 --> 1,1)? Can you skip cells (0,0 -> 2,0)?

Comment: "3. The algorithm is the fastest, on average. 4. The least amount of memory is used." This kind of "requirement" is meaningless. The fastest and the most space-efficient algorithm are usually not the same algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want the actual paths, and not just the number of them.

You can achieve it by using [**DFS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) that maintains `visited` set on the vertices explored in the **same path**, and avoids exploring a vertex that was already discovered in the same path.

**Pseudo code:**

```
DFS(v,target,visited):
   if (v == target):
      print path to v from the initial sorce
      return
   visited.add(v)
   for each vertex u such that u is a neighbor of v:
      if (u is not in visited):
          u.parent <- v
          DFS(u,target,visited)
   visited.remove(v)
```

invoke `with DFS(source,target,{})` [where `{}` is an empty `visited` set].

Answer (score 1):

The breadth-first search will do exactly what you want. When generating all paths there's no fastest

Comment: How will breadth-first search *all* paths. It typically terminates one path when it reaches a node which is already in the *visited* set.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713508/find-the-paths-between-two-given-nodes/713579#713579

Comment: I am sorry, but BFS without modifications will fail to find all paths. For example: find paths between (0,0) and (1,2): assume BFS yields the feasible path `(0,0)->(1,1)->(1,2)`, then it will not yield `(0,0)->(1,0)->(0,1)->(1,1)->(1,2)`, since BFS maintains `visited` set, and thus `(1,1)` will not be re-explored in the second path. If you have specific modification to BFS - please explain it with details, as standard BFS fails here.

Comment: Will get back to you later for the BFS solution - for now I've found in my lectures this source - recursive algorithm for finding all paths - http://pastebin.com/V0wNEpqY - it's publicly available as part of Telerik Academy's lectures ( http://academy.telerik.com/academy/csharp-programming-fundamentals/resources )

Comment: @t3hn00b: The algorithm there is a DFS, not a BFS.