# Get the best route between two dirrent paths in wp8

Tags: algorithm, windows-phone-8, graph-algorithm, path-finding

I have created a bus transit application for a city in windows phone 8. I have stored all my routes and bus stops in a separate table in the database.

My bus stop table contains:

```
stop_id |    stop_name              |   latitude   |  longitude   |    status   | alias_name
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
1736  |   Atlas Company         | 18.629243  | 73.833814  |  Active   | Centurenca Corner        
1737  |   Atlas company         | 18.629243  | 73.833814  |  Active   |    
681   | Atma Anand Dhyan Kendra | 18.600349  | 73.926251  |  InActive |
```

My Routes Table contains

```
bus_id |  bus_no | bus_source |  bus_destination | days_of_week | total_distance  estimated_time | source_stop_names | destination_stop_names | total_stops | source_trip_time | destination_trip_time | bus_status
```

`source_stop_names` contains

```
-----------------
  1  |  Swargate
  2  |  Parvati payatha
  3  |  Dandekar pul
  4  |  Pan mala Sinhgad Road
  5  |  Jal Shuddhikarn Kendra Sinhgad Road
  6  |  Ganesh mala
  7  |  Vitbhatti Sinhgad Road
  8  |  Vitthalwadi jakat naka
  9  |  Jaydeo nagar
  10 |  Rajaram pul
  11 |  Vitthalwadi Mandir Hingne
  12 |  Hingne rasta
  13 |  Anand nagar singhgad rd
  14 |  Manik Bag
  15 |  Indian hum company
  16 |  Wadgaon phata
  17 |  Patil colony
  18 |  Dhayari phata
  19 |  Sanas Vidyalaya
  20 |  Dangat wasti
  21 |  Gar mala
  22 |  Dhayarai gaon
  23 |  Raykar wasti
  24 |  Poultry farm singhgad road
  25 |  Dhayarigaon shala
  26 |  Chavan mala
  27 |  DSK Vishwa
```

I want to find the shortest path between two bus stops not connected by a bus route, and show the number of routes and buses the user has to take while travelling from one point to another, like google maps does.
I have used default map control in windows phone 8.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Comment: I have searched stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713508/find-the-paths-between-two-given-nodes but dont know how to show routes and buses the user has take while traveling from one point to another.And what according to you is the best way to ask a question.